# CoreDataでNSPredicate。CONTAINSでは取り出せるのに、他の方法で取り出せません。

Tags: objective-c, coredata

Storyという名前のエンティティ名でCoreData保存しました。

中身はattributeのみで、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このような構成になっています。

これをNSPredicateのCONTAINSを使って

> ```
>     NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Story"];
>     request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tap_count CONTAINS '0'"];
>     NSArray* result = [[DataBaseManager shared].moc executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
> ```

と書いたところtap_countが0,10,20の３つのNSManagedObjectが取れました。

でも本当はtap_count 0だけを取りたいので、

> ```
>     request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tap_count == '%d'",_tapCount];
> ```

だとか

> ```
>     request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tap_count MATCHES '[%d]'",_tapCount];
> ```

とかいろいろ試してみたのですが、うまく取り出せません。

取り出し方を教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

取り出せるようになりました。

`=`演算子を使うときは `==`ではなく、`=`なんですね。

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Story"];
NSString* predicateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tap_count = '%d'",_tapCount];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateStr];
NSArray* result = [[DataBaseManager shared].moc executeFetchRequest:request error:nil
```